# np.int32 object not iterable

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert text into a bunch of skipgrams with the help of Keras's Tokenizer. I have code that works for single sentences, but not for batches of sentences. Namely, when I try to run the method at the very bottom, I get an error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/montana/Documents/Capstone project/skipgrams.py", line 61, in
> word2vec_nn_generator
>     question_word_targets,question_word_contexts = sequences_to_skipgrams(question_sequences)   File
> "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
> line 1972, in __call__
>     return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)   File "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
> line 2042, in _vectorize_call
>     ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)   File
> "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
> line 2002, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
>     outputs = func(*inputs)   File "/Users/montana/Documents/Capstone project/skipgrams.py", line 54, in <lambda>
>     sequences_to_skipgrams = np.vectorize(lambda x: sequence_to_skipgrams(x,3,len(textTokenizer.word_index) + 1))   File
> "/Users/montana/Documents/Capstone project/skipgrams.py", line 48, in
> sequence_to_skipgrams
>     couples, labels = skipgrams(data, vocab_size, window_size=window_size)   File
> "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/sequence.py",
> line 197, in skipgrams
>     for i, wi in enumerate(sequence): TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/montana/Documents/Capstone project/skipgrams.py", line 72, in
> <module>
>     for i in word2vec_nn_generator(questionsTokenized_train,contextTokenized_train,trainingData["answer_start"],1):
> File "/Users/montana/Documents/Capstone project/skipgrams.py", line
> 65, in word2vec_nn_generator
>     raise ValueError("Exception in word2vec_nn_generator.") ValueError: Exception in word2vec_nn_generator. logout Saving
> session... ...copying shared history... ...saving history...truncating
> history files... ...completed.
> 
> [Process completed]
```

What exactly is this error message indicating, and how can I fix it?

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
assert os.path.isfile("train-v1.1.json"),"Non-existent file"
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
#import keras
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\W+')
#Reading the files.

def readFile(filename):
  with open(filename) as file:
    fields = []
    JSON = json.loads(file.read())
    articles = []
    for article in JSON["data"]:
      articleTitle = article["title"]
      article_body = []
      for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        paragraphContext = paragraph["context"]
        article_body.append(paragraphContext)
        for qas in paragraph["qas"]:
          question = qas["question"]
          answer = qas["answers"][0]
          fields.append({"question":question,"answer_text":answer["text"],"answer_start":answer["answer_start"],"paragraph_context":paragraphContext,"article_title":articleTitle})
      article_body = "\\n".join(article_body)
      article = {"title":articleTitle,"body":article_body}
      articles.append(article)
  fields = pd.DataFrame(fields)
  fields["question"] = fields["question"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["question"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["paragraph_context"] = fields["paragraph_context"].str.replace(regex," ")
  fields["answer_text"] = fields["answer_text"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["paragraph_context"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["article_title"] = fields["article_title"].str.replace("_"," ")
  assert not (fields["article_title"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  return fields,JSON["data"]

trainingData,training_JSON = readFile("train-v1.1.json")
print("JSON dataset read.")
#Text preprocessing
## Converting text to skipgrams

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams,make_sampling_table

def sequence_to_skipgrams(data,window_size,vocab_size):
  sampling_table = make_sampling_table(vocab_size)
  couples, labels = skipgrams(data, vocab_size, window_size=window_size)
  assert len(couples) > 0
  word_target, word_context = zip(*couples)
  word_target = np.array(word_target, dtype="int32")
  word_context = np.array(word_context, dtype="int32")
  return word_target,word_context
sequences_to_skipgrams = np.vectorize(lambda x: sequence_to_skipgrams(x,3,len(textTokenizer.word_index) + 1))

def word2vec_nn_generator(question_sequences,context_sequences,answer_starts,batch_size):
  while True:
    sequence_indices = np.random.randint(0,high=question_sequences.shape[0],size=10)
    question_sequences = question_sequences[sequence_indices,:]
    context_sequences = context_sequences[sequence_indices,:]
    try:
      question_word_targets,question_word_contexts = sequences_to_skipgrams(question_sequences)
      context_word_targets,context_word_contexts = sequences_to_skipgrams(context_sequences)
      yield question_word_targets,question_word_contexts,context_word_targets,context_word_contexts,answer_starts
    except Exception as e:
      raise ValueError("Exception in word2vec_nn_generator.")

strings = trainingData.drop("answer_start",axis=1)
strings = strings.values.flatten()
textTokenizer = Tokenizer()
textTokenizer.fit_on_texts(strings)
questionsTokenized_train = pad_sequences(textTokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainingData["question"]))
contextTokenized_train = pad_sequences(textTokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainingData["paragraph_context"]))

for i in word2vec_nn_generator(questionsTokenized_train,contextTokenized_train,trainingData["answer_start"],1):
  print(i)
  break
```

Comment: I'm unsure whether I can help with the actual question, but it's _really_ hard to read your code. _Nothing_ is gained by leaving out blank lines, but a lot is lost in intelligibility

Comment: Montana, can you provide the original traceback, because even with some formatting, the traceback is hard to read?

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.skipgrams` function receives a `sequence` argument in a wrong format.

Check the contents of the `data` variable in your `sequence_to_skipgrams` function and compare it with the required format:

```
sequence: A word sequence (sentence), encoded as a list
    of word indices (integers). If using a `sampling_table`,
    word indices are expected to match the rank
    of the words in a reference dataset (e.g. 10 would encode
    the 10-th most frequently occurring token).
    Note that index 0 is expected to be a non-word and will be skipped.
```

[Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/skipgrams)

The sequence is comming from the `question_sequences` variable, so, most likely, something is wrong with the way you slice it in the while loop (`word2vec_nn_generator` function).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

np.vectorize is not the function I wanted to use. np.vectorize assumes that it's given a function that takes a single value, such as a number.

What I wanted to do instead was np.apply_along_axis, which makes a different assumption: that the given function takes a 1-D array.